# Grepping for Manufacture

Tags: bash, awk, printing, grep

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.2.0/24 | awk '/Nmap scan report for/{printf $5;}/:/{print " => "$6;}' | sort
```

I get the following:

```
192.168.2.1 => 
192.168.2.10 => 
192.168.2.108 => 
192.168.2.120 => 
192.168.2.124 => 
192.168.2.126 => ITS,
192.168.2.135 => 
192.168.2.156 => 
192.168.2.158 => Network
192.168.2.168 => 
192.168.2.17 => 
192.168.2.3 => Computer)
192.168.2.44 => Co.)
192.168.2.50 => 
192.168.2.51 => Network
192.168.2.52 => 
192.168.2.54 => 
192.168.2.57 => Co.)
192.168.2.58 => 
192.168.2.59 => 
192.168.2.61 => 
192.168.2.65 => Precision
192.168.2.67 => 
192.168.2.68 => 
192.168.2.71 =>
```

What I am trying to do is grep and show only a specific manufacture but at this point I can't get the entire manufacture line to display.

The scans look like this:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.126
Host is up (0.00083s latency).
MAC Address: 30:CD:A7:A8:86:CC (Samsung Electronics ITS, Printer division)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.135
Host is up (0.00042s latency).
MAC Address: 00:27:22:E2:16:C2 (Ubiquiti Networks)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.156
Host is up (0.00019s latency).
MAC Address: 2C:41:38:A2:74:E9 (Hewlett-Packard Company)
```

Am I using AWK and Print wrong?

Answer (score 3):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/Nmap/{ip=$NF} 
       /^MAC/{$1=$2=$3=""; print ip " =>"  $0}' filename 
  | tr -s ' '
192.168.2.126 => (Samsung Electronics ITS, Printer division)
192.168.2.135 => (Ubiquiti Networks)
192.168.2.156 => (Hewlett-Packard Company)
```

There are many other ways but perhaps this is one of the shortest.  Setting fields to null string leaves the FS in place. Hence the `tr -s` to cleanup.